# Are there any special ways using a C++ standard to assign two values to two variables simultaneously?

Tags: c++, performance

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am not yet well versed in computer science. This is a question of algorithm speed.

I come across a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984077/project-euler-2) and I decide to tackle. My plan is to increment through the Fibonacci sequence as necessary to get an accurate result.

here is how I increment through;

```
unsigned int last(1), current(1) ;
unsigned int sum = 0 ;

looping
{
   ...
   current += last ;
   last = current - last ;
}
```

I feel like this is certainly as good as the increment needs to be, and probably as good as I can think of given my limited knowledge. But is there a special way to do that same increment using only those two variables? Perhaps I am wrong in my thinking, but would it be faster to do this instead:

```
temp = current ;
current += last ;
last = temp ;
```

there is visually one more statement than before, and one extra variable. They both do the same thing but I feel like one is quicker and uses less memory. Am I correct, which one is considered most efficient?

On a side note, I am not very experienced with using pointers, but am I right to assume that a pointer will not change very much since each piece of data is usually 4 bytes given the standard for int types? I can understand why a custom type that uses 50 bytes might be better to use a pointer though, but will it help with my second algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, no, no. Keep your code simple and clear. Obvious optimizations like this, when they are actually improvements, will be made by the compiler.

By the way, with GCC these two functions produce precisely the same 5 assembly instructions:

```
    void sum1(int * __restrict last, int * __restrict current)
    {
            int temp = *current;
            *current += *last;
            *last = temp;
    }

    void sum2(int * __restrict last, int * __restrict current)
    {
            *current += *last;
            *last = *current - *last;
    }
```

So GCC understands that they will always produce the same results and probably will treat them as equivalent in other contexts too. So use whichever one more clearly expresses your intent, is easier to understand and maintain, and so on.

Comment: thanks for the reassurance, I guess it does not matter if I know which one is faster then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
unsigned int last(1), current(1);

looping
{
    ...
    //`std::tie` creates a tuple containing references to `last` and `current`
    //`std::make_tuple` creates a tuple containing the new values. 
    std::tie(current, last) = std::make_tuple(current+last, current);
}
```

Comment: this is interesting, but will this reduce the work the processor will need by simultaneously making current last, and incrementing current by the previous value of last?

Comment: @Leonardo: As with most other forms of this code, the compiler will optimise the code into the most appropriate form for the processor being targeted. The important thing is readability and simplicity.

Comment: I do not know how to use this code, but it does take 20 times longer to run the code when I attempt.

Comment: @Leonardo: Do you have optimisation enabled when you are compiling it. I tried the two [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1jspjX$0) and they had comparable performance (with the std::tuple version actually being twice as fast as the manual version).

Comment: You are correct, I plugged in my function and it takes the same amount of time as the tuple. I did not enable optimization that is what caused it.